# How to export product Advance pricing in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, export, advanced-pricing

how to  export product Advance pricing  in Magento 2
Currently, I am using profiler to export product price but I didn't get
Advance pricing so how can I export Advance pricing store wise
in Magento 2
If any programmatically script and any tool then 
let me know fast.
Thank you.

Comment: Yahh good question I also need this...

Answer (score 0):

Hii Please use this code to get tier price

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product_obj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(1);                
$tier_price = $product_obj->getTierPrice();
if(count($tier_price) > 0){
    foreach($tier_price as $pirces){
        foreach ( array_reverse($pirces) as $k => $v ) {
            if($k == "price"){
                $tp = number_format($v, 2, '.', '');
                echo $tp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you
I use this code it's working but multiple customer group price can't  get and when tire price is empty in product then print price so how can i sorted it..